# xfce4-terminal geometry is scaled extremely small

Tags: freebsd, xfce, xfce4-terminal

I have a very interesting issue with xfce4-terminal and I don't know how to fix.

The geometry settings are scaled ***extremely*** small.  By that, I mean I have a geometry of 80 cols by 40 cols and I get a window that is effectively 27x3 (see below), which I think is the very minimum it will open.  If I specify 120x80, it's roughly the same.

[image]

However, if I change the settings in preferences to something outrageous like 5000x750 I get a normal sized window that doesn't need to be resized to be workable in.  This happens regardless if I set it in preferences or I launch it from CLI with the `--geometry` flag:

```
/usr/local/bin/xfce4-terminal --geometry 5000x750
```

I am using the Monospaced 12pt regular font, but I have tried changing to others to see if it had any effect, but nothing gives.

I don't have this issue in Xterm - I get an 80x40 window when I launch it.  I also don't have this issue with any other application that I lauch; just xfce4-terminal.

If anyone knows how I can fix this, I would be greatly appreciative.

FreeBSD 11.1, Xfce 4.12.

Comment: This might be a bug nearly identical to https://sourceforge.net/p/roxterm/bugs/125/ caused by GTK 3 changing how their APIs work

Comment: @IvanKozik- Wow...quite similar, though what's confusing is it's not using pixels as my resolution is 2560x1600.  I have to specify a pixel (colxrow) size over nearly 2x my resolution for less than a 1/4 of my actual screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by uninstalling and reinstalling the software.  Since it was originally installed via ports, I just issued the commands (as root)

```
# cd /usr/ports/x11/xfce4-terminal/
# make deinstall
```

Then reinstall

```
# make install clean
```

The interesting thing was it was a re-installation of the same version (not an upgrade) - v0.8.6.